# How do i get rid of this gap between the toolbar and the recycler view?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner in native android programming. Would like to seek some guidance and help to get rid of this gap in between the toolbar and my recycler view. Read through some write-ups on people who faced the same issue but majority of these had included a "Coordinator Layout" or "layout_gravity". However, I did not have those in my code. Tried many other ways but couldn't make it work.

[image: View the Image here!]

[Here is a picture that is based on the code! The embedded picture shows a better contrast for the gap. Sorry my account doesn't allow any embedding of photos yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5dq5.png)

1. Here is my code for the parent recycler view.

   ```
   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/rvProfile"
       android:layout_width="403dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
   ```
2. Here is the code for my individual item layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile"></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileUserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profileImage"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeProfilePicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileUserName"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profileImage"
        android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
        android:text="Change Profile Picture"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorLight"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changePasswordBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/changeProfilePicture"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profileImage"
        android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
        android:text="Change Password"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorLight"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"></Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/accountbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/primarylighest"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:text="Account"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/accountbar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Points"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsDisplay"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/accountbar"
        android:layout_marginStart="131dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pointsTxt"
        android:text="42 Points"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorLight"
        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderHistoryTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pointsTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text="Order History"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderHistBtn"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pointsDisplay"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="178dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/orderHistoryTxt"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
        android:rotation="180"></Button>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtExpenseTracker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/orderHistoryTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="Expense Tracker"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pointsDisplay"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="141dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtExpenseTracker"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
        android:rotation="180"></Button>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCurrencyConvertor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/orderHistoryTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:text="Currency Convertor"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pointsDisplay"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="176dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtPrivacyPolicy"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
        android:rotation="180"></Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/othersbar"
        android:layout_width="410dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="206dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/primarylighest"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:text="Others"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtShare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/orderHistoryTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:text="Share Krysjay with friends"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/othersbar"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtShare"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
        android:rotation="180"></Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPrivacyPolicy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/orderHistoryTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
        android:text="Privacy Policy"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/othersbar"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-97dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtCurrencyConvertor"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
        android:rotation="180"></Button>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTermsCons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/orderHistoryTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
        android:text="Terms &amp; Conditions"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/othersbar"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="105dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtTermsCons"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
        android:rotation="180"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signOutBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPrivacyPolicy"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
        android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:text="Sign Out"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to remove this line of code from your imageView?

```
android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help! Yes I tried removing that line but the gap still remained.

Comment: @Krystal Lim, Could you post the entire XML for that layout?

Comment: @Marco Malbasic here is the entire XML! I made some edits! Thank you!

Comment: @Krystal Lim, honestly for me it works fine... But in order to solve, I have tried using the ConstraintLayout instead of RelativeLayout. Check what I have done and try it

Comment: @Marco Malbasic I used this code however, the gap is still present. If it works for you, does that potentially mean that the problem lies with my emulator instead? But this occurs for all the different types of emulators i tried to run with.

Comment: No... There is nothing with your emulator... It must be something in your code... The only thing right now that is on my mind is your toolbar. Check the toolbar, pls

Comment: @Marco Malbasic alrights noted, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileImage"
            android:layout_width="111dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/profile"></ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accountbar"
            android:layout_width="410dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:background="@color/primarylighest"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:text="Account"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profileImage"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profileUserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/accountbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/profileImage"></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/changeProfilePicture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
            android:text="Change Profile Picture"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorLight"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/pointsDisplay"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.516"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/pointsTxt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/accountbar"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/changePasswordBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
            android:text="Change Password"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorLight"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/pointsDisplay"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/pointsTxt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/changeProfilePicture"></Button>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pointsTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Points"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/accountbar"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pointsDisplay"
            android:layout_width="157dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="131dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:text="42 Points"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorLight"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/pointsTxt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/accountbar"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderHistoryTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Order History"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pointsTxt"></TextView>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/orderHistBtn"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
            android:rotation="180"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/orderHistoryTxt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/changePasswordBtn"></Button>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtExpenseTracker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Expense Tracker"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/orderHistoryTxt"></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExpenseTracker"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
            android:rotation="180"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/txtExpenseTracker"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/orderHistBtn"></Button>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCurrencyConvertor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Currency Convertor"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtExpenseTracker"></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
            android:rotation="180"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/txtPrivacyPolicy"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnShareWithFriends"></Button>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/othersbar"
            android:layout_width="410dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/primarylighest"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:text="Others"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtCurrencyConvertor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Share Krysjay with friends"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/othersbar"></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnShareWithFriends"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
            android:rotation="180"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/txtShare"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/othersbar"></Button>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPrivacyPolicy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Privacy Policy"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtShare"></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCurrencyCovertor"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
            android:rotation="180"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/txtCurrencyConvertor"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnExpenseTracker"></Button>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTermsCons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="Terms &amp; Conditions"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtPrivacyPolicy"></TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTermsCond"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_back"
            android:rotation="180"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtTermsCons"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signOutBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtPrivacyPolicy"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
            android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:paddingStart="30dp"
            android:text="Sign Out"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtTermsCons" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```